# How to extend Int32 to add FromSomething?

Tags: c#, int, extension-methods

I'd like to add a method to the Int32 to do a "FromSomething" stuff.

Something that could allow me to write something like this:

```
Int32 i = Int32.FromSomething(mySourceData);
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What is `mySourceData` exactly? What do you want to get from it with `FromSomething` method?

Comment: @user3021830: No, extension methods don't allow you to add *static* methods to a type.

Comment: (The duplicate is talking about static classes specifically, but it's the same idea - trying to add a static method to an existing class. You can't do that.)

Comment: @user3021830: I don't know what you mean by that, but `System.Int32` is an existing *struct* (not class); `int` is the alias for it in C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet, nothing but I just need to sleep more :)

Comment: @Soner Gönül: In fact, I'd like to add a ".FromDecimalOrHex(string data)" and mySourceData could be either "10" (decimal value) either "0x10" (hexadecimal value) and put the logic of detecting the type inside this extension method. I ended up creating a Int32Helper class containing my static method. Thanks for your help.